# Partitioning the remainder of a bootable pen drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

Following [this advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880662/motherboard-replaced-how-can-i-recover-grub), I've used gnome-disks to create a bootable pen drive containing an image of xenial.     After doing so, here's what the pen drive looks like[image]

I'd like to use the rest of the drive, however, when I try to put a new partition onto the unallocated space, `gparted` tells me  [image]

Presumably the primary partition is `/dev/sdb2`, which I obviously don't want to remove.    I've also tried resizing /dev/sdb2, but when I attempt to do this,  gparted spins forever, issuing the following warning:  [image]    If I click on ignore, I get an error and the resize fails.

Is there any way to get to use the rest of my drive?       My ideal would be to partition the pen drive *before* making it bootable with gnome-disks, but I'm pretty sure that I can't do that. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Do not know what Disks actually does to create installer.  And most installer Creation instructions are assuming a smaller USB flash drive and the standard install erases entire drive. And if using the dd method or behind the scene using dd, that is a hybrid flash drive/DVD configuration that does not have a valid partition table. Is system UEFI or BIOS? And better to use flash drive as installer and then use hard drive as data or full install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB%20Installation%20Media

Answer (score 0):

Create an `extended` partition.  This is a special type of partition that will allow you to create virtually an unlimited amount of partitions.

Once you create the extended partition, you will see the available space as usable.

Comment: Trouble is, I don't see how to create an extended partition *after* I've made the drive bootable.    Only way gparted will let me do that is if I first delete the primary partition, but then, I've killed my Ubuntu image, and am back to square one.     Is there any way to create an `extended` partition on the drive *before* using gnome-disks to create the image?

Comment: @LeoSimon Sorry.  I missed the part that you were trying to reconfigure an Installer disk.  That isn't possible.  Almost anything that you do to it could make it non functional.  It would take some sophisticated programming to create an alternate installer disk.  You can make a bootable disk and modify the partitions in unlimited says.  But an installer disk, isn't just a bootable disk.  It's a preconstructed image.  The image uses the entire disk.  The partition table would have to be modified to for changes to happen... continued

Comment: ... the explanation was about to overflow a second comment limit.  I'll append the details to the answer later.