# Boot-repair stuck on "Unhide boot menu". Grub for dual boot recover after motherboard replacement

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04
Trying to recover grub after motherboard replacement.

I used live-USB to try to recover grub with boot-repair. After it stuck on "Unhide boot menu" I stoped the process. And turned off computer.
Computer automaticaly booted to Windows previously. Now i get Grub 2 terminal on boot, just
grub>

Also, when checking in grub, i couldnt find grub.cfg in default location: /boot/grub and also /boot/efi
What should I do?

Here is the boot repair info I got: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w6y4MSFqHp/

Last lines of code from boot-repair log before it stuck on "Unhide boot menu":

```
SET@_label0.set_text('''Purge and reinstall the GRUB of: sdb4 (fin). This may require several minutes...''')
SET@_label0.set_text('''Unhide boot menu. This may require several minutes...''')
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb4/etc/default/grub
[debug] sda1 ends at 525336064GB. not-far
Presence of EFI/Microsoft file detected: /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Presence of EFI/Boot file detected: /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
Presence of EFI/Boot file detected: /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/fbx64.efi
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
[debug] sda3 ends at 111896461824GB. farbios
[debug] sda3 ends at 111896461824GB. farbios
[debug] sda4 ends at 112790076928GB. farbios
[debug] sda4 ends at 112790076928GB. farbios
[debug] sda5 ends at 126870355456GB. farbios
[debug] sda5 ends at 126870355456GB. farbios
[debug] sda6 ends at 128035323392GB. farbios
[debug] sda6 ends at 128035323392GB. farbios
[debug] sdb2 ends at 751754542592GB. farbios
[debug] sdb2 ends at 751754542592GB. farbios
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()

=================== sdb4/etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Mar 14 21:45 grub.d
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Mar 14 21:37 grub.d.bak
total 76
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10046 Nov 11 05:52 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6258 Mar 18  2019 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12693 Nov 11 05:52 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 Nov 11 05:52 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Nov 11 05:52 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Nov 11 05:52 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Nov 11 05:52 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Nov 11 05:52 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Nov 11 05:52 README




=================== sdb4/etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"



/boot/efi detected in the fstab of sdb4: UUID=3883-5F9E     (sda1)
[debug] sdb4 ends at 1000204542976GB. farbios
[debug] sdb4 ends at 1000204542976GB. farbios
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
[debug]End fix /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/etc/grub.d/
```

Comment: At the end I decided to do it manually. Good explanation can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/880662/motherboard-replaced-how-can-i-recover-grub. I found one answer which seems as most logical one, but it was too late to try it out because I already used boot-repair. If you have similar situation and didnt do anything yet, I would suggest to try this first: https://askubuntu.com/a/1119507/1034078

Comment: Also, when refering to first link, keep in mind: System partition- one with linux installed on (you will see root/ there for example). In my computer it was on separate hard drive in partition 4: sdb4. Efi partition- one where efi files. Try using gparted to check location of previous partitions. For disk you need to chose disk which is your boot disk, you can check it in BIOS in boot section. For the reason that grub will be installed in MBR of that disk, so it would run automatically when you turn computer on.